# Emulating browser cache for each VU from K6 for load testing

Tags: javascript, load-testing, k6

I understand k6 cannot emulate browser cache (except cookies in header) as per its documentation.

Has someone attempted to simulate browser cache (more than just cookies header) while load testing with k6 tool ?

Looking for functions / options like: 
1. Switch on/off browser caching.
2. Clear cookies at the start of each iteration.

Trying to understand how headers like Etag, Expires, Last-Modified, Cache-Control, If-None-Match or If-Modified-Since can be handled from k6 script for each resource. 
Not sure, if something more needs to be checked while trying to handle browser cache.

If yes, kindly share some ideas on how to do so or share github repo for any ongoing/successful project. 
If successful, possibly can be contributed to k6 repo once verified.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with the automatic cache handling in k6, since it doesn't have such functionality yet (https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/issues/142). But regarding cookies, that's the default k6 behavior - it resets cookies between iterations. You can disable that behavior with the `noCookiesReset` [option](https://docs.k6.io/docs/options).